# Upgrade debian 32 bit to 64bit

Tags: debian

I have debian file 32bit provided by the customer, which contains their products, Now that they want to upgrade it to 64bit, I can't find a solution.
Someone help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "debian file" ? What is the "product" ?

Comment: I want to install the .deb 32 bit file on ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, but this error has occurred:
sudo dpkg   -i    opensdk_package-<version>.deb

Comment: VERSIONS:3.50
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of opensdk-package-3.50:i386:
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on g++ (>= 4.1.1).
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on gcc (>= 4.1.1).
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on libc6-dev.
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on libtar-dev (>= 1.2.11).

Comment: opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on libssl-dev.
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on libssl-ocaml.
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386 depends on make.
dpkg: error processing package opensdk-package-3.50:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opensdk-package-3.50:i386

Comment: Since it is a compiled binary package, it would seem that you'd need the source, set up a build environment on a 64bit machine, and rebuild the binary and then rebuild the package.